# Should CIImage be Equatable?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, ciimage, equatable

So, Apple’s documentation says that `CIImage` conforms to `Equatable`. I would take this to mean that the following unit test would pass. However, it doesn’t. I’m interested in why.

```
func test_CIImageEqualityShouldWork() {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: PrototypeTests.self)
    guard let path = bundle.pathForResource("testImage", ofType: "png") else { return }
    guard let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) else { return }

    let thingy1 = CIImage(image: image)
    let thingy2 = CIImage(image: image)
    XCTAssert(thingy1 == thingy2)
}
```

The image exists, the `guard` statements both pass, but the assert fails, they aren’t equal.

Out of interest, I’ve tried creating the `UIImage` twice and comparing those too. That also fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `NSObject` subclasses conform to `Equatable`, and the `==` function
calls the `isEqual:` method on the objects.
 The `isEqual:` method
of `NSObject` simply compares the object pointers, i.e. `o1 == o2`
holds if `o1` and `o2` refer the same object instance.

See for example
[Interacting with Objective-C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35):

> Swift provides default implementations of the == and === operators and
>   adopts the Equatable protocol for objects that derive from the
>   NSObject class. The default implementation of the == operator invokes
>   the isEqual: method, and the default implementation of the ===
>   operator checks pointer equality. You should not override the equality
>   or identity operators for types imported from Objective-C.
>
> The base implementation of the isEqual: provided by the NSObject class
>   is equivalent to an identity check by pointer equality.

Many `NSObject` subclasses override the `isEqual:` method (e.g. `NSString`,
`NSArray`, `NSDate`, ...) but not `CIImage`:

```
let thingy1 = CIImage(image: image)
let thingy2 = CIImage(image: image)
```

creates two different `CIImage` instances and these compare as "not equal".

Comment: Hmm, interesting. So, I also tried converting them each to a `UIImage`, then converting those to `NSData` and comparing that – still failed, even with identical images from the bundle. Should that work?

Comment: @lukech: You convert  PNG file -> UIImage -> CIImage -> UIImage -> PNG data. I would not expect that the data is identical.

Comment: I would. Perhaps that’s naive, though. Anyway, this seems like the correct answer to my question, so much obliged, thank you :)

Comment: If you want to compare two images to see if they contain identical content, you might want to check out this repo: https://github.com/FlexMonkey/ImageCompareDemo

Answer (score 0):

FlexMonkey's [ImageCompareDemo](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/ImageCompareDemo) was an incomplete port from facebook's [ios-snapshot-test-case](https://github.com/facebookarchive/ios-snapshot-test-case/blob/master/FBSnapshotTestCase/Categories/UIImage+Compare.m) in C++ to Swift. It left out the last part of pixel per pixel comparison. Mine is in Swift 4, here's the whole function:

```
static func compareWithImage(reference:CGImage, target:CGImage, tolerance:CGFloat) -> Bool {
    guard reference.width == target.width && reference.height == target.height else { return false }
    let referenceImageSize = CGSize(width:CGFloat(reference.width), height:CGFloat(reference.height))
    let targetImageSize = CGSize(width:CGFloat(target.width), height:CGFloat(target.height))
    let minBytesPerRow = min(reference.bytesPerRow, target.bytesPerRow)
    let referenceImageSizeBytes = Int(referenceImageSize.height) * minBytesPerRow
    let referenceImagePixels = calloc(1, referenceImageSizeBytes)
    let targetImagePixels = calloc(1, referenceImageSizeBytes)
    let referenceImageCtx = CGContext(data: referenceImagePixels,
                                      width: Int(referenceImageSize.width),
                                      height: Int(referenceImageSize.height),
                                      bitsPerComponent: reference.bitsPerComponent,
                                      bytesPerRow: minBytesPerRow,
                                      space: reference.colorSpace!,
                                      bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
    let targetImageCtx = CGContext(data: targetImagePixels,
                                   width: Int(targetImageSize.width),
                                   height: Int(targetImageSize.height),
                                   bitsPerComponent: target.bitsPerComponent,
                                   bytesPerRow: minBytesPerRow,
                                   space: target.colorSpace!,
                                   bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
    guard let referenceImageContext = referenceImageCtx, let targetImageContext = targetImageCtx else {
        return false
    }
    referenceImageContext.draw(reference, in:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:referenceImageSize.width, height:referenceImageSize.height))
    targetImageContext.draw(target, in:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:targetImageSize.width, height:targetImageSize.height))
    var imageEqual = true
    if(tolerance == 0) {
        imageEqual =  (memcmp(referenceImagePixels, targetImagePixels, referenceImageSizeBytes) == 0)
    } else {
        let pixelCount = Int(referenceImageSize.width * referenceImageSize.height)

        let p1 = convertUMRPtoUInt32Array(pointer:referenceImagePixels!, length:referenceImageSizeBytes)
        let p2 = convertUMRPtoUInt32Array(pointer:targetImagePixels!, length:referenceImageSizeBytes)
        var percent:CGFloat = 0
        var numDiffPixels = 0
        for n in 0..<pixelCount {
            if(p1[n] != p2[n]) {
                numDiffPixels += 1
                percent = CGFloat(numDiffPixels) / CGFloat(pixelCount)
                if (percent > tolerance) {
                    imageEqual = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //print(percent)
    }
    referenceImagePixels?.deallocate(bytes:referenceImageSizeBytes, alignedTo:1)
    targetImagePixels?.deallocate(bytes: referenceImageSizeBytes, alignedTo: 1)
    return imageEqual
}
```